# Postgres Join Query on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have researched a lot and I can't find the answer for my question. I have the following setup on my Rails app:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  # ...
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  # ...
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :group
  # ...
end
```

The people have the column `:role` that is `0` or `1`.

I want to get all the groups that have at least one person with `role == 0` and one person with the `role == 1`.

Any idea? I'm using Postgres by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query I just tested on my SQLite3 database (should work on Postgres too I believe):

```
 Group.select("groups.*").joins("LEFT JOIN people on groups.id = people.group_id").where("people.role==0 OR people.role==1").group("id")
```

Here I assume you've already added the foreign key group_id in your people migration.  Hope this helps.